# ¿Por qué traducimos "I didn't know" como "no sabía" en lugar de "no supe"?

Tags: traducción, verbos, pretérito

Cuando queremos llevar la traducción de una oración de inglés a español, comúnmente usamos el imperfecto en variados casos, a saber

> *I didn't know = No sabía.*

Pero, ¿por qué no decir *no supe*?

Para el nativo del inglés, ¿es siempre *didn't know* pretérito perfecto? Pues los nativos del español llevamos verbos en pasado del inglés ya sea para usarlo como pretérito perfecto o imperfecto.

Comment: Angloparlantes e hispanoparlantes.

Comment: Haha, sí, no sé por qué lo dejé así.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`I didn't know` si se puede traducir como `No supe`. La diferencia esta en que en Español hay dos formas con sentidos ligeramente diferentes.

Ocurre durante un período:

> **No sabía** qué hacer *durante* el examen (I didn't know what to do during the test)

Evento puntual:

> **No supe** qué decirle cuando me preguntó (I didn't know what to say when she asked)

Como lo dije, el sentido es ligeramente diferente pero ambos en inglés se dicen como `I didn't know`

Comment: Esta respuesta es excelente. Se distingue claramente no solo para este verbo sino también para otros usos.

Comment: De manera que la traducción en su ejemplo dependería del contexto; "no sabía" o "no supe"; sin embargo pienso que por lo general; si sólo se tiene "I didn't know", yo optaría por la primera forma, siendo que "no supe"  me parece incómodo sin algo adicional, como "no _lo_ supe" o "no supe _hacerlo_".  ¿Será por que uno puede tener sabor y saberle a alguien?

Comment: @David eso es lo bonito del español. :-) Existen dos formas. El imperfecto se refiere a una acciòn duradera, repetida o habitual del pasado mientras el pretérito se refiere a una acciòn del pasado considerada terminada.

Comment: @DGaleano, tiene razón y me fascina el español. Yo agregaría que el imperfecto no limita la acción al pasado.  Por ejemplo: yo mentía sugiere pero no asegura que la acción no se repita; al igual en el caso the "no sabía".  Que piensa Ud?

Comment: @David en realidad no tiene que ver con que la acción se repita o no en el futuro sino más bien con que la acción tuvo una duración o con que la acción se repitió habitualmente en el pasado. _Yo mentí_ = lo hice una vez (aunque lo pueda volver a hacer) _Yo mentía_ = quiere de decir que lo hice por algún tiempo o que lo hice en repetidas ocasiones (sin importar que de igual forma lo podré volver a hacer en el futuro)

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener en cuenta que no es lo mismo **No supe** a **No sabía** pues a pesar de que ambos describen acciones que son en el pasado el primero habla de un caso puntual y el segundo de una acción que tiene una duración.

Ilustrando en un ejemplo lo que deseo que comprendas:

Durante el verano pasado no sabía (*marcando una duración*) donde estaba mi libro preferido, pero ayer lo supe (*marcando un momento puntual*).

Answer (score 0):

Para decir "No supe" se puede utilizar:

- "I had no idea"
- "I had no clue"

En inglés el término "I have not" se usa como preposición del verbo en su pretérito perfecto.

Comment: _Para decir No supe, se utiliza: "I had no idea or I had no clue"_ <------Not necessarily.

Comment: @TeachingTom How would you say it then?

Comment: If we are talking about a person who didn't know something, then it is ok to say I had no idea.